# What's the Mac equivalent for CTR+ALT+Backspace on Linux?

Tags: keyboard, switching

I need to regularly shutdown brutally my Mac, due to program misbehavior (Starcraft 2 and EVE Online), which take control of the graphics and never surrender it back.

While I admire the tenacity of those embattled programs... I'd rather nuke them with a single stroke, as I would on Linux by killing the X server.

The irritating part is, the underlying OS runs fine, since I can move the mouse around, change luminosity or sound. I just can't switch back to anything, work, email... so I have to fully reboot.

How do I do that? What's the secret key combo?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> opens the "Force Quit Application" 
dialog, which lets you select and kill running applications.

If that does not work,

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> held down for 5 seconds kills the foremost application.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer. I'll mark it accepted as soon as I get a new hang and can test it. Given Eve's stability, it should not be long :D

Comment: Dang, havent played Eve in like 8 years

Comment: Whoa! That second command is powerful! Thank you so much for revealing that handy little secret. It is very helpful.

Comment: @Fake Name - wow!  I didn't know about the 2nd command.  Very nice.

Comment: The fact that these shortcuts are not better-known is one of the ongoing issues with macs. *Everyone* knows Ctrl+Alt+Delete, but the mac equivalent is nearly unknown. Yet in my experience, i experience a roughtly equal number of crashes on each platform (it largely comes down to the software, not the platform itself). As such, people generally wind up rebooting their macs far more often then one would have to reboot the equivalent windows computer.

Comment: Frankly, apple **really needs** a ctrl+alt+delete equivalent. On windows, ctrl+alt+delete will aggressively grab control of the screen back from the running application, letting you then get to a working desktop-view again. The fact that there is not such a facility on apple devices is an ongoing issue, at least for me.

Comment: I have never had a scenario where I've needed a Ctrl+Alt+Del, except Kernel Panics, in which case it tells you to use the button and that's not hard. (Plus, when the kernel panic screen occurs, the keyboard is worthless anyways.)

Comment: @Jason Salaz - I probably used 'Force Quit' more then five times yesterday alone. Admittedly, I'm rarely in a situation similar to the OP's, where I need to forcibly re-take control of the keyboard, but it does happen. In particular, in my case, I have an issue where the Dock-Spaces-Switcher gets in contention with Apple Remote Desktop, and as a result, the Dock app begins swallowing all key-presses. It results in a situation where even Cmd+Opt+Shift+Esc no longer works, and the only option is a reboot.